# Smart CSS compressor that moves @imports to top

Tags: node.js

I've written a little script that gathers up all my CSS files and compresses them:

```
var cssSources = [];

bundle.input.stylesheets.forEach(function(filename) {
    if(isLocalPath(filename)) {
        var fileContents = FileSystem.readFileSync(filename, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        if(/\.css$/.test(filename)) {
            cssSources.push(fileContents);
        } else if(/\.less$/.test(filename)) {
            var parser = new Less.Parser({
                paths: [staticDir],
                filename: filename
            });
            parser.parse(fileContents, function(e, tree) {
                cssSources.push(tree.toCSS());
            });
        }
    }
});

var cssCode = UglifyCSS.processString(cssSources.join(''));
```

Which was working well until I tried `@import`ing a font in a CSS file that was not included *first*. This means that the `@import` wound up somewhere in the middle of my compressed CSS, which of course doesn't work.

I'm currently using UglifyCSS as you may have noticed; is there a better alternative that will move all the `@import`s to the top? Preferably available as an `npm` package.

**Update:** [clean-css](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) has the same problem.

Comment: @icktoofay: Well, Chrome and Firefox won't load it if it's not at the top. If you want me to cite a source rather than using empirical evidence, [this random blog](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.UiPKbzakrAk) says: "Your `@imports` must come before all other content in your CSS. And I mean all of your content. Even putting comments before the @import tag will cause your imports to fail. So be sure to do your imports before you do anything else."

Comment: I see. I guess I had never tried doing that before and so never ran into that problem.

Comment: Run into the same problem. I'd expect a decent merge-and-minify tool to expand imports as part of merge process.